# splitting sentences of a number list by its numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, split

i am quite new to javascript,
Lets say i have this:

```
const text = "1. foo. 2. bar. 3. baz";
```

this is a json returned from calling api,
is there any way to add a new line after a number index so that i can look like this when output:

1. foo.
2. bar.
3. baz.

i want to make it like a

i tried to split by "." but it does not work and repeatedly giving

```
1.foo
1.foo
3.baz
3.baz
```

is there any way to do that?

Comment: care to share the code that you tried?

Comment: First instinct: Regular expression.

Comment: Please add more details. If your data can only contain a single word, you could split on [digit][dot].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex and replace all numbers with a white spaces before and a dot after with a new line + the match characters. Also you would probably want to trim the prefix white spaces:

```js
const text = "1. foo. 2. bar. 3. baz.";

console.log(text.replace(/(?<!^)\s*(\d+\.\s+)/g, '\n$1'));
```

Comment: ah thank you, may i also ask if there is no space between . and the word how can i split it?
like 
` const text = "1.foo 2.bar 3.baz";`
and wanting to get the same result up there how would it needed to be?

Comment: @baguette fixed, not can split without spaces between

Answer (score 0):

The OP's required result can be achieved by a simple [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) task which ...

- does (globally) replace *"each dot followed by at least one space and at least one digit"* ([`/\.\s+(\d+)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/3LnxBQ/1)) by *"a dot, a new line and the [captured](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) digit sequence"* ([`'.\n$1'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_the_replacement)).

```js
console.log(

  '1. foo. 2. bar. 3. baz.'

    // - see ... [https://regex101.com/r/3LnxBQ/1]
    // - replace each dot followed by at least one
    //   space and at least one digit by a dot, a
    //   new line and the captured digit sequence.
    .replace(/\.\s+(\d+)/g, '.\n$1')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```